# Product of PyTorch tensors along arbitrary axes à la NumPy's `tensordot`

Tags: matrix-multiplication, pytorch, dot-product

NumPy provides the very useful [`tensordot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html) function. It allows you to compute the product of two `ndarrays` along any axes (whose sizes match). I'm having a hard time finding anything similar in PyTorch. `mm` works only with 2D arrays, and `matmul` has some undesirable broadcasting properties.

Am I missing something? Am I really meant to reshape the arrays to mimic the products I want using `mm`?

Comment: @M.Deckers: How could it? It doesn't even take arguments to specify which axes to take the product along.

Comment: It is not available at the moment but currently discussed [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/8988).

Comment: @McLawrence: Thanks, that's very clarifying!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by @McLawrence, this feature is being currently discussed ([issue thread](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/8988)).

In the meantime, you could consider [`torch.einsum()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/torch.html#torch.einsum), e.g.:

```python
import torch
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(36.).reshape(3,4,3)
b = np.arange(24.).reshape(4,3,2)
c = np.tensordot(a, b, axes=([1,0],[0,1]))
print(c)
# [[ 2640.  2838.] [ 2772.  2982.] [ 2904.  3126.]]

a = torch.from_numpy(a)
b = torch.from_numpy(b)
c = torch.einsum("ijk,jil->kl", (a, b))
print(c)
# tensor([[ 2640.,  2838.], [ 2772.,  2982.], [ 2904.,  3126.]], dtype=torch.float64)
```

Answer (score 4):

The original answer is totally correct, but as an update, [Pytorch now supports `tensordot`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.tensordot.html) natively. Same call signature as numpy but change `axes` to `dims`.

```py
import torch
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(36.).reshape(3,4,3)
b = np.arange(24.).reshape(4,3,2)
c = np.tensordot(a, b, axes=([1,0],[0,1]))
print(c)
# [[ 2640.  2838.] [ 2772.  2982.] [ 2904.  3126.]]

a = torch.from_numpy(a)
b = torch.from_numpy(b)
c = torch.tensordot(a, b, dims=([1,0],[0,1]))
print(c)
# tensor([[ 2640.,  2838.], [ 2772.,  2982.], [ 2904.,  3126.]], dtype=torch.float64)
```